# How to select a div element that does not have a class?

Tags: html, dom, tags, queryselector

```
Sample HTML Element
<div data-testid="Custom Data Test">
```

- The above div does not have a class inside.
- How do I access, "data-testid" (which selector should I use)

Comment: If you are using jQuery, you can use **this** keyword like that `$(this).attr( "data-testid" )` to get the clicked div data-test attribute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelector()` or `querySelectorAll()` and select by attribute like this:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div[data-testid="Custom Data Test"]');
div.textContent = "blah";

const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-testid]');
divs.forEach( (e,i) => e.textContent = e.textContent + " this is div number " + i + " and data-testid attribute is " + e.dataset.testid);
```

```html
Sample HTML Element
<div data-testid="Custom Data Test"></div>

<div data-testid="Custom Data Test 2"></div>
<div data-testid="Custom Data Test 3"></div>
```

Comment: In a dynamic environment where the value of `data-testid` can keep changing is there a way where I can find the value of data-testid

Comment: Thank you !!
Really appreciate